# Print each section on a separate invoice

Tags: c#

Welcome
I finished creating my sales invoice, but unfortunately I have a problem,
I want when I sell items each batch is printed in only one invoice.
Example:
If I have 6 items in grid view, and every 2 items belong to one group number, it will print in one invoice where 3 invoices will be printed if 6 and every 2 items are in group

picture for clarification
[image]

The code used for printing

```
 int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
        DataTable tblRpt1 = new DataTable();
        tblRpt1.Clear();

        string sql = @"SELECT [Order_ID] as 'رقم الفاتورة',talb_ID as 'طلب',[Cust_Name] as 'اسم العميل',Products.Pro_Name as 'المنتج',Products.Group_ID as 'قسم',Products_Group.Group_Name as 'اسم القسم',[Sales_Detalis].[Qty] as 'الكمية',[Price] as 'السعر',[User_Name] as 'الكاشير',[Date] as 'التاريخ',[Unit] as 'الوحدة',[Sales_Detalis].Tax_Value as 'الضريبة',Price_Tax as 'السعر بعد الضريبة',[typetalab] as 'نوع الطلب',[priceservic] as 'خدمة',[shiftname] as 'شيفت',notes as 'ملاحظات',shiftnum as 'شيفت رقم'
FROM
    [dbo].[Sales_Detalis]
    INNER JOIN Products
        ON Products.Pro_ID = Sales_Detalis.Pro_ID
    INNER JOIN Products_Group
        ON Products.Group_ID = Products_Group.Group_ID
WHERE
    Products.Pro_ID IN ({0}) AND Order_ID = {1}
ORDER BY Order_ID ASC";

        var productIds = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= DgvSale.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (DgvSale.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value == DgvSale.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value)
            {
                productIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DgvSale.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
            }
        }

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.SalePrintKind == "8CM" && productIds.Count > 0)
        {

            string commandText = String.Format(sql, String.Join(", ", productIds), id);
            tblRpt1 = db.readData(commandText, "");

            devOrderSales2 rpt = new devOrderSales2() { DataSource = tblRpt1, DataMember = "OrderSales2" };
            rpt.DataSource = tblRpt1;
            rpt.Parameters["ID1"].Value = id;
            rpt.PrinterName = Properties.Settings.Default.PrinterNameSteker;
            rpt.xrTableCell8.Visible = true;
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.saleprintauto == "0")
            {
                rpt.Print();
            }
            else if (Properties.Settings.Default.saleprintauto == "1")
            {
                rpt.ShowPreviewDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question. Your code doesn't explain what the problem is

Comment: The attached code itself has no problem. I'm just looking for a way to print custom as I mentioned, and only help is to modify the attached code

Comment: There are probably hundred ways to do that. You need to try yourself first - that's big part of joy of programming! Frankly, if it is too complex - you may need to use https://www.upwork.com/ for help and not Stack Overflow

Comment: I've tried a lot, unfortunately, I don't know where to go wrong, and I'm here to learn too

Comment: you need to share what you tried; that's how SO works. and also what problem you encountered. Just saying "I've tried a lot" isn't convincing.